# Getting the song location and play selected treeNode

Tags: c#

hi i have been trying for a while with this before i resorted to here

heres in my current code

```
 private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedNodeText = e.Node.Text;
            string location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
            mediaPlayer.URL = location + "\\" + selectedNodeText;
        }
```

//
heres how i load the treeView

```
string music = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(music);
        if (directoryInfo.Exists)
        {
            treeView1.AfterSelect += treeView1_AfterSelect;
            BuildTree(directoryInfo, treeView1.Nodes);
        }
    }
    public void BuildTree(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, TreeNodeCollection addInMe)
    {
        TreeNode curNode = addInMe.Add(directoryInfo.Name);

        foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            curNode.Nodes.Add(file.FullName, file.Name);
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            BuildTree(subdir, curNode.Nodes);
        }
    }
```

it plays the selected treeNode in mediaplayer but its not playing a song from a sub directory in music any help will make my day 
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the selectedNodeText value when you select a sub directory?

Comment: its just giving me the song name  + extension there is no path hence why its not loading the song in media player :/

Comment: Are you asking or stating?

Comment: asking lol...........

Comment: Can you show the code where you are loading the treeview nodes?

Comment: it wont let me put it in my post now so i put it in a pastie in the post have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectedNode only has the song name. When you try to play the sound from a sub directory, you are missing the sub directory from the path and hence it is not playing. You are currently using the **Base Music Directory + Song Name**.

In the case of a sound file in a sub directory you need to build the path using **Base Music Directory + Sub Directory + Song Name**

You can get this Sub Directory, either by saving it in your `Tree Node Tag` or build it from the `Tree Heirarchy`.

Additionally, use `System.IO.Path.Combine`. It will save you the trouble of slashes and joining strings to create a valid file path.

In your example you could add the full path to the TreeNode Tag and then use it to play the file later.

```
public void BuildTree(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, TreeNodeCollection addInMe)
{
    TreeNode curNode = addInMe.Add(directoryInfo.Name);

    foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        TreeNode musicNode = curNode.Nodes.Add(file.FullName, file.Name);
        musicNode.Tag = file.FullName;
    }
    foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        BuildTree(subdir, curNode.Nodes);
    }
}
```

And then to play the file

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedNodeText = e.Node.Text;
        //Ensure that this is not a directory node
        if (e.Node.Tag != null) {
            string location = e.Node.Tag; 
            mediaPlayer.URL = location;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the info im a newbie so still learning atm so do you have some sort of source for this please?

Comment: @user3506486 Add your section of code which loads the tree view in your original post and I can help you.

Comment: @user3506486 Updated the answer based on your code.